# How to style specific a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styling

I have a lot of links look something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/nigahiga">Youtube</a>
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/41236152807615600/">Pinterest</a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/manchesterunited">Facebook</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/RayWilliamJohnson">Youtube</a> 
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/24910604158520050/">Pinterest</a>
```

How can I style only the hyperlinks that will be linked to `pinterest`. I tried this:

```
$('a').attr('href').contains('pinterest').css('Styling here');
```

But it does not work. How to achieve it?

Comment: Did you see the error message in the console and read why that did not work? contains() does not work on a string which attr returns. If you used something like indexof or match or test, you could get away with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('a[href*="pinterest"]').css('color','DeepSkyBlue');
```

or better just need pure css:

```
a[href*="pinterest"] {  
    color: DeepSkyBlue;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YdbAq/)**

Comment: true, you can pu more in ...css({ color: '#aaf', background: '#444', margin: '20px' })

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('a[href*="pinterest"]').css('apply styles');
```

Selector documentation can be found at http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

```
For attributes:

= is exactly equal
!= is not equal
^= is starts with
$= is ends with
*= is contains
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the hyperlinks linked to pinterest using the next selector:

```
$('a[href^="http://pinterest.com/"]')
```

That selector will return all the 'a' elementas where 'href' attribute starts with http://pinterest.com/

Then you can style them

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the attribute contains solution (although not as neat), you could also use the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function:

```
$('a').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr("href").indexOf("pinterest") != -1;
}).css('color', 'red');
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/q56PZ/)

Answer (score 0):

You should check every a's href attr value.

$('a').each(function(){

if($(this).attr('href').contains('pinterest'))

$(this).css (your style);

});